# Can comma categories of small categories be understood as limits/colimits in $\textbf{Cat}$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits

Let $F: C \to D$ be a functor of small categories. One can form the comma categories $F/$ and $/F$ with objects
\begin{align*}
(c,d,\phi) && \phi: F(c) \to d \\
(c,d,\psi) && \psi: d \to F(c)
\end{align*}
where $c\in Ob(C)$, $d \in Ob(D)$, and $\phi,\psi \in Arr(D)$. Can these categories be expressed as a limit or colimit in $\textbf{Cat}$?

Comment: Yes, comma categories are 2-pullbacks in Cat: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/comma+object

Answer (score 3):

To be a pedant, I think the term "2-pullback" is ambiguous, and perhaps should simply be *defined* to be a comma object, which is not quite the same thing as a lax pullback. The objects of the lax pullback category of functors $F: A \to C$ and $G: B \to C$ consist of quintuple $(a \in A, b \in B, c \in C, Fa \overset{f}{\to} b, b \overset{g}{\to} Gc)$, whereas the objects of a comma category consist of just a triple $(a \in A, b \in B, Fa \overset{f}{\to} Gc)$.

There is a variant where you require the maps $f,g$ to be invertible, resulting in the notions of *iso-comma category* and *pseudopullback*, which, though not isomorphic, are equivalent. But comma categories and lax pullbacks need not even be equivalent, as for example in the case of slice and co-slice categories.

Note that in order to view a slice or coslice category, or more generally a comma category, as a limit, you need to think in terms of *weighted* limits in the $\mathsf{Cat}$-enriched sense, as discussed [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-limit).

Comment: The term "2-pullback" actually means something quite different from a comma object.  To an Australian-style 2-category theorist, it means a *strict* (Cat-enriched) pullback, while on the nLab it is sometimes used to mean a weak pullback up to isomorphism (what an Australian would call a "bipullback").  Comma objects and lax pullbacks are both something different (and different from each other).